# How to tie into Illuminate events Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, events, laravel-5.3, listeners

I want a message on my applications login page when the event of logout is trigged under `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php`.

Since this is in core I thought it would be as simple as adding:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\Logout' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogoutEvent',
    ],
];
```

as stated in https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events#registering-events-and-listeners

But after running artisan command it just creates a spot for me to make my own event. So my question is, can I listen to core events in Laravel like Logout without creating my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to listen for this event, however, the event isn't in your `App` namespace.

The namespace for the core Auth events is `Illuminate\Auth\Events` so you would have:

```
 protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogoutEvent'
    ],
];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought I tried that! Either way worked like a charm. Thanks